# Force Between two Bar Magnets (Gilbert's Model)

Tags: electromagnetism

We have a lab project on forces between two bar magnets. Description says the force between two bars are inversely proportional to the 4th power of distance between magnets, according to Gilbert's model, but i couldn't find any relevant source or equation explaining this theory on the whole internet. Can anyone please help me with that or share any link?

Here's the exact assignment:

"*When bar magnets are modeled as two monopoles with opposite magnetic charges (Gilbert’s Model), it is found that for large enough distances, force is proportional to magnetic strengths of both magnets, and inversely proportional to the 4th power of distance between magnets. Main objective is observing if this approximation is accurate enough. Experimenter should find a way to measure force on one of the magnets, and use at least 4 different magnetic strengths and 7 different distances to see the pattern. Careful data analysis needed (log log graphs to get the experimental exponent, etc.)*"

Comment: Did you see [Wikipedia: Force between magnets: Gilbert model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#Gilbert_Model)?

Comment: Yes, the problem is it includes the length of bars into that "4th power", but the lengths of bars don't change.

Comment: Look at the very end of section "*Gilbert Model*".
The final formula there is $F(x) = \text{some constants} \cdot \frac{1}{x^4}$.